# File does not exists when uploading it fo FTP

Tags: swift, ftp, record

I want to record a sound and upload it to FTP
I used this to upload my file over FTP https://github.com/Constantine-Fry/rebekka and I am in swift 3, so let's look at my code:

To record a sound

```
@IBAction func rec(_ sender: Any) {
    let file = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0].appending("/rec.m4a")
    let url = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: file)    
    let format = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat64, sampleRate: 32000, channels: 2, interleaved: true);
    do {
      recorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: url, format: format)
      recorder?.prepareToRecord()
      recorder?.record()

    } catch {

    }     
}
```

and to upload it to FTP

```
@IBAction func svp(_ sender: Any) {
   recorder?.stop()
   var configuration = SessionConfiguration()
   configuration.host = "matr.fr"
   configuration.username = "mat"
   configuration.password = "a"
   let file = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0].appending("/rec.m4a")
   let filename = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: file)
   let URL = filename
   let path = "/rec.m4a"
   Session(configuration: configuration).upload(URL, path: path) { (result, error) -> Void in
     print("Upload file with result:\n\(result), error: \(error)\n\n")     
   }
}
```

But i have this error:

> Upload file with result:
>   false, error: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=2 "(null)" UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/mathieu/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C30D070A-292C-4735-87AA-C3C13D0BCA28/data/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/9CDBEAD1-7170-4BB5-86AB-B1D58F148635/Documents/rec.m4a})

Comment: using simulator? It won't work. Simulator mic is not supported. So you need to try using a device

Comment: is the file name correct? one is rec.m4a and one is rec.wav

Comment: I have the same error on device `Upload file with result:
false, error: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=2 "(null)" UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/3A56D89C-C0A0-40F1-B820-16DFE36DB0A3/Documents/rec.m4a})`

Comment: you have added `let path = "/rec.wav"` as filename in svp action event

Comment: Yes I renamed it to "rec.m4a" and the same error

Comment: use this to find the directory: `FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("rec.m4a")`

Comment: I tried this to find the directory in the 2 functions, but the error is still here :/

Comment: instead of this `let path = "/rec.m4a"` do like this `var a = URL(fileURLWithPath: "rec.m4a")` and at time of upload do like this `.upload(URL, path: a.path)`

Comment: The same error, sorry again